# get rid of decoration around buttons in WPF

Tags: wpf, button, focus

I want to get rid of this dotted border around my button

[image: dotted border on focused elements]

It looks like it is related to focus, specially when is the selected item (after a click) but the focus goes to another window

Comment: it is probably buttons default `FocusVisualStyle`. try set it to null: `<Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/> `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed setting the

```
FocusVisualStyle = "{x:Null}"
```